# No counter numbers in titles of outline in pdf bookmarks sidebar with hyperref

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

I have manipulated the counters of sections, subsections and subsubsections. If I view the ready document in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 15.010... than the manipulated counters of section, subsection and subsubsection are displayed correctly. But they didn't appear in the bookmark sidebar. My manipulation somehow broke the communication with the `hyperref` package.

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperref}

\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

  \section{Fragen}

    \subsection[generalisierte Koordinaten]{\hypertarget{q_i}{generalisierte Koordinaten}}
      Sind Größen $ q_1, \dots, q_s $, die die Lage eines Systems vollständig beschreiben.

    \subsection{generalisierte Kräfte}
      Sind den \hyperlink{q_i}{generaliserten Koordinaten} zugeordnet.

    \subsection{Potentielle Energie}
      Technischer Systeme, z.\,B.

      \subsubsection{Eine Saite}
        Die Länge einer gespannten Saite beträgt:
        \begin{align*}
          l &= l_0 + \Delta l\\
            &= \ldots
        \end{align*}
        Für die kinetische Energie ergibt sich, siehe \hyperlink{Stab}{Stab}:
        \begin{align*}
          K &= \frac{\mu}{2} \int \limits_{0}^{l} \dot{w}^2 \mathrm{d} x\\
            &= \ldots
        \end{align*}

      \subsubsection[Ein Stab]{Ein \hypertarget{Stab}{Stab}}
        \begin{align*}
          U &= \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} U_i\\
            &= \ldots
          \intertext{Die kinetische Energie eines Stabes:}
          K &= \int \limits_{0}^{l} \frac{v^2}{2} \mathrm{d} m\\
            &= \ldots
        \end{align*}

  \section{Verschiedenes}

    \begin{description}
      \item[Freiheitsgrade]$ s = 3N - g $, mit Anzahl der Teilchen $ N $ und Anzahl der Zwangsbedingungen $ g $.
      \item[Sonst]$ \ldots $
    \end{description}

\end{document}
```

How can one fix this?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `bookmarksnumbered`:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Ulrike Fischer! Thank you for your answer! It's an easy one! I learned from your answer that the bookmarks are not numbered by default. Never noticed it. Thank you for this knowledge too!